# Make Mega menu visible on focus, not just hover

Tags: css, keyboard, accessibility, focus, megamenu

I'm trying to make a mega menu visible on focus, not just hover. Not sure what I'm doing wrong - it's at https://deltadentalcofoundation.org/ Here's the HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-main-2022" class="nav-menu dl-menu submenu-icon styled">
    <li id="menu-item-31816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-parent menu-item-31816 megamenu-template-enable megamenu-first-element mobile-clickable menu-item-current" data-template="32343">
        <a href="https://deltadentalcofoundation.org/about-us/">About Us<i class="default"></i></a><span class="menu-item-parent-toggle"></span>
        <div class="megamenu-template template-width-fullwidth template-framing-border megamenu-template-item-inited megamenu-template-inited">
```

The CSS to make div.megamenu-template visible on hover is as follows:

```
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li:hover > .megamenu-template {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: transform 0.3s linear, opacity 0.3s linear, visibility 0.3s linear;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

From what I understand, I can't focus on the li, so I've been trying to focus on the a nested inside the li, and then using the adjacent selector to make the div.megamenu-template visible. I've tried all the below, but can't make it work... any ideas?

```
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li > a:focus + .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li > a:focus-visible + .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li > a:focus-within + .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li:focus-within > .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li:hover > .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li:focus-within > .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li > .megamenu-template:hover,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li:focus-visible > .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li:focus-within > .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li > .megamenu-template:focus-visible,
ul.nav-menu > li:focus-visible > .megamenu-template,
ul.nav-menu > li:focus-within > .megamenu-template,
ul.nav-menu > li > .megamenu-template:focus-visible,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > a:focus > .megamenu-template,
.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > a:focus-visible > .megamenu-template {
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition: transform 0.3s linear, opacity 0.3s linear, visibility 0.3s linear !important;
    transform: translateY(0) !important;
}
```

Comment: `.thegem-te-menu__default.desktop-view ul.nav-menu > li:focus-within > .megamenu-template` would be the correct one. If it didn’t work, did you inspect your code to see whether the selector and the properties apply?

Comment: You were right - focus-within was the way to go! The code was correct but the CSS wasn't loading properly - I think it was a caching issue.

Comment: Glad it works now. Would you mind accepting the answer then, if it’s what worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot focus the `<li>` itself, and the mega menu needs to stay open once focus moves away from the triggering, parent item to its child items.

Therefore, your only choice is `:focus-within`.

```css
.megamenu-template {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu-item:focus-within .megamenu-template {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu dl-menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">About Us <i aria-hidden="true" class="default"></i></a><span class="menu-item-parent-toggle"></span>
        <div class="megamenu-template">
        MEGA MENU
        <a href="#">Submenu item</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Menu item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If in your example this didn’t work, it might be due to other selectors or missing classes elsewhere.

Use your browser developer tools to investigate.

---

Don’t forget to either hide your icons from assistive technology with `aria-hidden` or providing an alternative text.

Also, the current page should be marked in the link with `aria-current="page"`.

See also the [ Example Disclosure Navigation Menu  on the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/disclosure/disclosure-navigation.html

They don’t open submenus on focus, but via toggles.